# How do I get an HP LaserJet CP1025 color printer working?

Tags: hp

i have hplip 3.10.6 and it doesn't show any driver for 'Hp Laserjet cp1025 color'. is there a way to get the driver install?

Answer (score 4):

seems you need version 3.11.1 for this printer.

The instructions on [this page](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html) may help, follow the instructions on how to install the newer hplip package. I believe the installer will remove the older hplip.

The version of HPLIP that supports your printer is here:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_cp1025.html

Comment: i thank you very much for your precious help. the hplip is up-to-date now, and my printer works fine.

Comment: Glad it works :)

Comment: Worked on my raspberry pi. All methods failed, until I loaded the latest drivers from the links you supplied.